# HTML-Comments most readable

Tags: html, comments

I am wondering how html-comments on bigger section-blocks can get structured in the most readable, strucuturally easy to recognize way?

I do mine as this:

```
        ....</section>

                    <!--      _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
4th Block: Contact sheet  _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_ -->

        <section class ....
```

I know this takes a bit of file-size, but 1. you can autoreduce it on a live-system and 2. it really helps in finding, rearranging and structuring semantic blocks more easily (in my experience)

I'd be interested in how you do that? How do your comment-blocks look like?

Comment: I've started a minimal standard and dubbed it 'HTMLDoc'. You can read about it here: http://usehtmldoc.org/. It's quite similar to JSDoc and other similar standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a matter of personal preference, however if you are working within a team, you should all agree on a unified format.That is said, I prefer just keeping it simple with the standard HTML tag and that is it.